# Spring Rest API Oauth2 Security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth

I'd like to secure a Spring Rest Service via OAuth2.
I have a Oauth2 Authorization Server running at localhost:9500. I can get a Bearer Access Token for a user (Grant type = Password)

My Service running at localhost:9000/api should be protected by OAuth2. Anonymous should not be able to access the service. Only Users authenticated by the Authorization Server should be able to use the service.

That is my definition of the Rest Service:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "api", path = "api")
interface StreckeRepository extends MongoRepository<ApiEntity, String> {
}
```

With this, anonymous access is possible.

I added this for security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  public static final String RESOURCE_ID = "api_service";
  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
  }
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .anonymous().disable()
      .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/")
      .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
  }
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
    final RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:9500/oauth/check_token");
    tokenService.setClientId("web");
    tokenService.setClientSecret("secret");
    return tokenService;
  }
}
```

But now I get an error 401: Full authentication is required to access this resource. Even if I access it, with Header Authorization Bearer + Access token.

What is missing to get it working?

Comment: How is your resource server verifying the token with the authorisation server? There is not enough information here to see what is going on.

Comment: Put your `WebServerConfigurereAdapter` also.

Comment: That's all I have so far. What must the WebServerConfigurerAdapter be like? For Token Verification I added a tokenService() Method to the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter (see edited post above)